# Regarding IE 10 issue while overriding the native DOM methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

**JS**

```
var _getElementById = document.getElementById;
//override document.getElementById
document.getElementById = function (id) {
    var _elem = _getElementById(id);
    eval("_elem." + name + " = fn");
    return _elem;
};
```

It works fine in IE9, but now this javascript is not supported in IE10.
I'm getting Error in this Comment

```
var _elem = _getElementById(id);
```

while page loading.
Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: I don't understand the code. Why use eval?

Comment: What exact error do you see? A fiddle would help too.

Comment: Nice hack btw, I'll check it in IE and try to find an answer. But my first guess is that your storing reference of old getElementById some how not permitted, but I am not sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get this error, document's getElementById method seems to be bind to document object yet I am not 100% sure why this only occurs on IE10, yet you can easily overcome by storing reference to original function inside document object. See:

```
document._getElementById = document.getElementById;
//override document.getElementById
document.getElementById = function (id) {
    var _elem = document._getElementById(id);
    eval("_elem." + name + " = fn");
    return _elem;
};
```

Btw, this still raises errors since name variable is not defined. That is trivial I guess.

Comment: I am using this code for override the document.getElementById to document._getElementById. But it showing 'SCRIPT28: Out of stack space ' Error.please provide solution for that.

Comment: You have to give a complete code example that produces the error you describe, in my version I was able to work without errors, I cannot give solution unless I access your code that produces the error.